# What does the key creation parameters do when creating RSACng?

Tags: .net, rsa

What does the options for CngKeyCreationParameters.KeyCreationOptions actually mean?  One of the option is CngKeyCreationOptions.OverwriteExistingKey, why would there be an already existing key if I'm creating one?  What does it mean to set it to CngKeyCreationOptions.MachineKey?  Bit confused because if I'm wanting to create a key, how does this option effect key creation?

Comment: Have you looked at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.cngkey.create?view=net-5.0#System_Security_Cryptography_CngKey_Create_System_Security_Cryptography_CngAlgorithm_System_String_System_Security_Cryptography_CngKeyCreationParameters_)? You can create persistent keys with a name, and that key can be stored for the current user or for the system.

Comment: Ok, so the key is persisted if there is a keyname provided and the CngKeyCreationOptions.MachineKey determines where it is persisted (localMachine or CurrentUser).   How about the OverwriteExistingKey?  Why would there be an existing key if I am creating one?

Comment: I'd have to look up the intricacies of the MS key store, but either they were created under the same name by other sw (not sure if this is possible), or you'd create two persistent keys under the same name, replacing one with the other. The name is used to lookup the persisted keys.